# How to connect reactjs file with css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I don't have a huge website, but I still want to maintain css separate from my js files.

My folder structure:

```
static
    css
        style.css
    js
        landing.js
```

In my landing.js file, I have: `import styles from '../css/style.css';`

With the above mentioned setup, I am getting this error:
`react-dom.production.min.js:12 Uncaught Error: Minified React error #130;`

Am I doing something wrong? If I must use something like webpack to avoid getting minified errors, why is that the case? Why can't I just use simple CSS?

Note: I'm not using JSX

Comment: Can you please update your question with `webpack` config?

Comment: @HardikModha I guess that's part of my question. Am I forced to use something like webpack to add style?

Comment: Oops, I missed it. The `import` statement that you have used is part of the `ES6` spec and `ES6` is not (yet) fully supported in all browsers. So you'll need to use `babel` to compile your code which browser can run. Using `webpack` will make it easier to add plugins like `babel`, and then for loading the CSS files you can use `css-loader` and `style-loader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For importing `css` in `.js` files in `reactJs` env you need to set up [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader).

But if you don't want to play around with `webpack` or other bundlers, include your `css` in `html` file for now.

Other variant is write inline css in your `React` component, or use stylesheets like [Radium](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium).

Answer (score 2):

Link the css file from your main html file where you have the root div of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing it in **styles** just include your css like this

```
import '../css/style.css'; // ES5
require('../css/style.css');
```

later after compilation it will become part of your build.